# Algorithm to recover missing 12th word (of 12) in BIP39 mnemonic

Tags: mnemonic-seed, wasabi-wallet

I'm trying to recover my Wasabi wallet. For some reason the 12th word of the 12-word mnemonic I wrote was wrong (not in BIP39 list). I could manually guess up to 2048 times, but was hoping there might be an algorithmic way to work through an array of the 2048 words and associate the result with my public keys for the wallet to find the right word.

I'm a newbie programmer, so any guidance on an approach to solve would greatly help and help me avoid a long manual slog. Thanks.

Comment: There is a 4-bit checksum, and there is code such as https://github.com/bharathrao/bip39check to list words that satisfy the checksum, so that should cut you down to roughly 128 possibilities.

Comment: That definitely makes it a more manageable manual task... thanks Nate!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost my Bitcoin wallet and have only 11 out of 12 mnemonic seed phrase words. How can I get my Bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/78987/lost-my-bitcoin-wallet-and-have-only-11-out-of-12-mnemonic-seed-phrase-words-ho)

Comment: I created a little tool for this a while back: https://sutterseba.github.io/. Make sure to run it offline and verify the code first.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check up to 128 variants. Try this software: https://kzen-networks.github.io/mnemonic-recovery/src/index.html

Comment: Please be very careful before entering even key information into a random website, and make sure to review the code.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion & caution and I'll try it with the code on an air-gapped PC.

Comment: This is almost a link-only answer. And the link is no longer valid (error 404)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Seed Tool: https://bitcoiner.guide/seed/

Comment: We generally like answers to be a more elaborate here. Since the asker stated that he is a programming novice, you could for example further explain how the asker would use the tool to recover the missing word. Note that we generally remove link-only answers as low-quality.