# Lost Bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet, lost-wallet

If I have wallet address only, part seed phrase can I get access to Bitcoin wallet. Can bitcoin.org find IP logs from date of wallet download.

Answer (score 1):

> Can bitcoin.org find IP logs from date of wallet download.

No. Bitcoin.org mostly provides links to sites that provide downloads. Their website has no way of knowing if you clicked on a provided link.

Even if they were able to keep a log of IP-addresses and chose to retain that log long term, I doubt you would be helped by a list of IP-addresses that were mostly dynamically assigned by ISPs.

> If I have wallet address only, part seed phrase can I get access to Bitcoin wallet.

See

- [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/13866)
- [Difficulty of brute-forcing a seed with missing words?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/65476/13866)
- [19 out of 24 words of BIP39 passphrase (brute-force last 5?)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/87326/13866)